# WAMP server. Very large data directory in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver

I have problem with wammp server. 
In directory "..\WampServer\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\data" was created files with very large size. 
Full size of this directory is 50GB. What is these files? How can I fix this problem?

The names of files are:

```
mysql-bin.000001
mysql-bin.000002
................
mysql-bin.000227
```

The size of all files is 49GB

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What information about the  data ?

Comment: you can delete them its working fine after deleting them

Comment: the better place for this question is [serverfault](http://serverfault.com)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By default whenever you make a change to a MySQL database it creates a log of the query and stores it in a file simlare to `mysql-bin.000001`. The MySQL database does this so that you can recover or replicate a database. Most applications this is a good things to have enabled just like doing regular backups.

If you want to disable MySQL from creating these binary logs:

1. Open `my.ini`
2. Search for this line `log-bin=mysql-bin`
3. Comment this line out by adding a hash mark: `# log-bin=mysql-bin`
4. Save and restart the MySQL database

You can now safely delete these files from that directory.

Comment: How can I view content on these files ?

Answer (score 7):

I did another thing on my wamp...
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/purge-binary-logs.html

Start a command prompt and goto directory wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.16 or whatever version number you got

type:

```
mysql.exe -u root
SHOW BINARY LOGS;
```

a list with all the log files will be show up. We need the last one.
In my case was mysql-bin.000412

so i typed

```
PURGE BINARY LOGS TO 'mysql-bin.000412';
```

and you are ok!

Comment: The data directory contains all of your declared databases. If you are no longer using or want some of them, you can with care delete them.