# Why is mysqlserver.lib file very large? Is this file neccessary in wamp stack?

Tags: mysql, server, wamp, wampserver

Recently I created my development server using php7.0.1, mysql5.7 and apache 2.4.20.

After I successfully got it running, I checked the file size of my server and found that it is almost 2 GB.

So I digged further and found that mysqlserver.lib file inside mysql/lib folder is around 976 MB.

So my problem is how can I make my server file size smaller?

Is this `mysqlserver.lib` safe to delete?

I don't see mysqlserver.lib in the `wamp2.5` version of mysql.

Any suggestion for making file size in mysql community edition smaller is welcome.

Comment: The `lib` folder is there for you to compile MYSQL yourself if you want. So it is not required for normal running. I would rename the `lib` folder first just to be sure, but as long as you dont want to recompile MYSQL yourself you should be able to safely remove the whole folder.

Comment: Yes, it works without the lib folder. Thanks.

Comment: for distributions that include embedded server libraries, the corresponding library names are mysqlserver.lib, libmysqld.dll, and libmysqld.lib.

Comment: how to delete some files is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444191/wamp-server-very-large-data-directory-in-mysql

Comment: @RiggsFolly You should write your answers in the answer section so they can be reviewed and accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `lib` folder is there for you to compile MYSQL yourself if you want. So it is not required for normal running.

So as long as you dont want to recompile MYSQL yourself you should be able to safely remove the whole folder.