# How to install a light version on mysql

Tags: mysql

I install `mysql` with a batch file, but the mysql install file 'mysql-installer-community-5.7.11.0.msi' is so big : **387MB**.
Does a mysql light version exist ? 
The computer does not have internet so the `mysql-installer-web-community` is not recommended for me.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a batch-file problem  Removing the tag.  This question is also off topic for SO.

Comment: Did you look at using SQLite? https://www.sqlite.org/

Answer (score 4):

Download [MySQL as zip archive](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=467269)---a so-called *noinstall archive*---and see what you can strip off. When finished, repackage the remaining file into a much smaller zip.

Candidates for deletion include:

- bin/mysqld.pdb (~160 MB): [debug symbols](https://serverfault.com/questions/315352/delete-pdb-files-from-mysql-bin-folder)
- [embedded server libraries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/c-api-implementations.html) (~1,05 GB):

  - lib/mysqlserver.lib
  - lib/libmysqld.dll
  - lib/libmysqld.lib
- lib/plugin/debug/* (~180 MB)
- [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404066/why-is-mysqlserver-lib-file-very-large-is-this-file-neccessary-in-wamp-stack) indicates you could even remove the whole lib folder

(Note that I did not test if the installation actually succeeds without these files)

**Repackaging with Ultra compression (7zip) gives me a 110 MB zip file.**

On the target machine, just follow the [installation instructions for noinstall archives](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-install-archive.html). They go well together with a batch-based installation.